# How to assign a number to each user?

Tags: parse-platform

I need to get some batch of User objects and assign a number to each. Actually that's easy if you need to get just User objects, but what if I need to get User objects where some field equal to some value, but numbers must be the same when I just getting User objects by simple query?
For example we have 4 Users

1. name=Nick, score=43, someValue=false
2. name=John, score=47, someValue=true
3. name=Dick, score=50, someValue=false
4. name=George, score=58, someValue=true

With User query which using OrderBy("score") I can get next batch of users

- Nick (number 1)
- John (number 2)
- Dick (number 3)
- George (number 4)

But then I want to get users where someValue=false, but the numbers must be the same, so it must be like this

- Nick (number 1)
- Dick (number 3)

So I wonder, can I do all that thing by using only ParseUser.Query, without downloading a big batch of users and deleting users where someValue==false?

p.s. sorry for my bad English and thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Cloud.html
for this particular scenario.

Here is the official document and help how to work with Parse Cloud Code.
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code

Comment: Aah, I know about this, but if there are too many requests, I guess it will load Parse too much. Yeah, users will spent less traffic, but Parse will spent more CPU power. IDK what is better.